# Ansible playbook fail install apt

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to do a test installation on remote via ANSI, and I can not run the Apt-get, attached images:

Playbook

[image: Playbook]

Error

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

`apt` would require root privileges. Add:
`become: true`
to your playbook. Ensure that `user` has the required sudo privileges.

Comment: It would be easier if you enable password-less sudo with `NOPASSWD: ALL`

If you do not with to, you can prompt for the password:

`$> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -K`

If you pass the password as an argument, you can use:


`$> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars='ansible_become_pass="XXXX"'`

I have not had any luck using this with special characters in the password.
My password for instance has `!` and `@` characters. I've tried escaping, using JSON etc. but it only works when I have simpler alpha-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the quick response, it is very urgent to fix this bug and get install via ansiable. Now I ask for a password, I tried putting the user and password in the execution sentence of the playbook:

ansible-playbook playbook.yml --user=username --sudo-pass=yourPassword

ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --user=username --sudo-pass=yourPassword

ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --user=username \ --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=yourPassword"

ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --user=username \ --extra-vars "ansible_become_pass=yourPassword"

You could tell me how to enter the pass.

The sentence of the playbook is as follows:

"---
 - hosts: webservers
   remote_user: user
   tasks: 
     - name: install example
       apt: name:filezilla state=present
       become: yes 
"

Billion thanks

[actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YP4B.jpg)